# Compilation problem

Tags: tables

sorry, but I'm new to latex.
I do not understand why this latex does not compile in PDF ...
Can somebody help me please
thank you in advance

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{slashbox} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{ulem} 
\usepackage{nccrules}
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{shapepar} 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tablists}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\DecimalMathComma 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{glossaries} 
    \makeglossaries
    \renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{{#1}*}
    %\setglossarystyle{listgroup}
    \loadglsentries{monglossaire}

\begin{document}


chapter{l'optique ondulatoire}\label{chapOptiqueondulatoire}

\section{Introduction a l'optique ondulatoire}\label{SecIntroOptOndul}

\subsection{Ondes}\label{subsecOndes}

\vspace{5mm}

{\centering
\boxput*(0,1){ %commande pour placer la 1ère boite devant la 2eme
    \colorbox{white}{\textbf{Définition lumière}}
        }{
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}   
    \ovalbox{\parbox{15cm}{
                une onde est un transport d'énergie sans transport de matière. Elle est concrétisée par la perturbation d'un milieu
        }}

\vspace{5mm}

La théorie ondulatoire de la lumière est apparu dans les années 1600 par Christiaan Huygens. On appelle onde, la propagation d'une perturbation d'un milieu. La vitesse de ces ondes dépend des propriété physique du milieu traversé. De plus, la nature physique et temporelle de la perturbation est déterminée par la source de celle-ci. Il existe différent type d'ondes.
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\cline{1-1}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Ondes} & Point de déplacement                                                                                                          & Perturbation                                                     & Exemple                                            &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Transversales}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}perpendiculairement\\  par rapport à la direction de propagation\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{direction perpendiculaire à celle de l’onde} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{lancer de corde}               &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Longitudinales}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}la \\ même direction\\  que celle de propagation\end{tabular}}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{la même direction que celle de l’onde}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{un ressort, les ondes sonores} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
                                         &                                                                                                                               &                                                                  &                                                    & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Les ondes peuvent avoir des phénomène periodique, c'est a ditre qui se répète dans le temps, ou de double periodicité, qui en plus de se répéter dans le teps elle se répète dans l'espace. On appelle ces ondes les ondes progressive.\\

Lorsque l'on travaille avec une onde progressive sinusoïdale, on obtient la fonction d'onde suivant : \\

\centering 
$s(x,t)=s_0\cos\left(\omega\left(t-\dfrac{x}{v}\right)\right)+\varphi_0$ Avec :\\

$s_0$ : Amplitude \\
$\omega=\dfrac{2\pi}{T}$ : Pulsation et $T$ la longueur d'onde\\
$\varphi_0$ : Phase à l'origine\\


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code contained many errors. Have a look at the output of your compiler and read the errors since it tells you where the mistakes are located. You load many packages, that you do not need, so I deleted them.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %changed to uft8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{{#1}*}
%\setglossarystyle{listgroup}
%\loadglsentries{monglossaire} %caused an error

\begin{document}


\chapter{l'optique ondulatoire}\label{chapOptiqueondulatoire} %\ added

\section{Introduction a l'optique ondulatoire}\label{SecIntroOptOndul}

\subsection{Ondes}\label{subsecOndes}

\vspace{5mm}

{\centering
\boxput*(0,1){ %commande pour placer la 1ère boite devant la 2eme
\colorbox{white}{\textbf{Définition lumière}}
    }{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}   
\ovalbox{\parbox{15cm}{
            une onde est un transport d'énergie sans transport de matière. Elle est concrétisée par la perturbation d'un milieu
    }}}}

\vspace{5mm}

La théorie ondulatoire de la lumière est apparu dans les années 1600 par Christiaan Huygens. On appelle onde, la propagation d'une perturbation d'un milieu. La vitesse de ces ondes dépend des propriété physique du milieu traversé. De plus, la nature physique et temporelle de la perturbation est déterminée par la source de celle-ci. Il existe différent type d'ondes.
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\cline{1-1}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Ondes} & Point de déplacement                                                                                                              & Perturbation                                                     & Exemple                                                &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Transversales}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}perpendiculairement\\  par rapport à la direction de propagation\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{direction perpendiculaire à celle de l’onde} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{lancer de corde}               &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Longitudinales}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}la \\ même direction\\  que celle de propagation\end{tabular}}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{la même direction que celle de l’onde}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{un ressort, les ondes sonores} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
                                     &                                                                                                                               &                                                                  &                                                    & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Les ondes peuvent avoir des phénomène periodique, c'est a ditre qui se répète dans le temps, ou de double periodicité, qui en plus de se répéter dans le teps elle se répète dans l'espace. On appelle ces ondes les ondes progressive.\\

Lorsque l'on travaille avec une onde progressive sinusoïdale, on obtient la fonction d'onde suivant : \\

\centering 
$s(x,t)=s_0\cos\left(\omega\left(t-\dfrac{x}{v}\right)\right)+\varphi_0$ Avec :\\

$s_0$ : Amplitude \\
$\omega=\dfrac{2\pi}{T}$ : Pulsation et $T$ la longueur d'onde\\
$\varphi_0$ : Phase à l'origine\\


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes to deleting unnecessary `\usepackage` commands! Perhaps also suggest a more appropriate structure for the centred material at the end.